# How to re-order number or change to be date format dd/mm/yyyy in PosgrestSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My question, now I have table customer in Postgresql and contain the column name is update (for keeping track of update customer info date.) 
The date format is ex:`20170302` but I want to convert to be `02/03/2017`.

Note: the datatype of the update is character varying.

I have tried several times to find all the solutions by google but not fix.

Comment: Store dates in date type column, not varchar!

Comment: Why don't you use a Date field instead of a text-based field? That has all kinds of benefits. If you really *do* need to keep it as text, your current format is a much better one IMO - it's naturally sortable, for starters...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. First time to create this database was other person.
So it so hard to re-configure.

Thank you very for coming.
Thanks,

Comment: It is not clear whether you want to change the column data type or just the display format.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto, I just want to display in date format only.
Are there any way that faster and no need to change data type?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

First, you should fix the data type to be a proper `date` or `datetime`.  Don't store dates as strings!

But you are.  You can convert the value to a date and then back to a string:

```
select to_char(to_date(update, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) contains the formatting elements that you can use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will try once again.

Thanks.

Comment: Dear Sir,

Can I do like this? in case of my table name is customer and the column name is update.



Ex: select to_char(to_date(update, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') from customer






Any suggestion very appreciate.

Thanks once again.

Comment: Fix the column type first. Something like: `ALTER TABLE blah ALTER COLUMN blahcol TYPE date USING (to_date(blahcol, 'YYYYMMDD')` . (*understand this* before doing it)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I tried to change the data type to be date type and using script that you provided me to query but not work also.

here is the error: ERROR:  function to_date(date, unknown) does not exist

Sorry,

Comment: Dear Sir,

It's working well. We should eliminate the to_date out such

select to_char(upddate,'DD/MM/YYYY') from customer

Thank you very much for kindly help me on this.
Thanks,